# Overriding my.conf template in RDS using AWS OpsWorks

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, rds, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to change my RDS instance default character set to `utf8mb4` so I can support emojis. I have a [repo with all my recipes](https://github.com/FanBread/opsworks-cookbooks), which I've used in the past to customize my deployments. I followed [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/cookbooks-101-opsworks-templates.html) from AWS, but when I deploy the app, the changes aren't reflected in the database. I also made sure to create a `metadata.rb` file in the root of the `mysql` directory in my custom cookbooks repo.

I also setup a new RDS instance using a new property group where the appropriate character sets and collations are set to `utf8mb4`. This DB is also set as my datasource in my app in OpsWorks.

In Rails, I also set the encoding and collation to `utf8mb4`...

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
  ...
```

If I ssh into my application server and then connect to MySql, this is what I see when querying for global variables...

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

But when I do the same for non-global variables, I see this:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                      |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                      |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.23.R1/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I should also mention that this works fine locally after I set the appropriate tables and columns to `utf8mb4` using a migration.

At this point, I can't figure out why I can't get the character sets to apply correctly. Hopefully someone smarter than me can help me figure this out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After digging a bit deeper, I realized that I missed a critical step when updating custom cookbooks. I didn't realize that simply doing a deployment wouldn't retrieve the new recipes. After I ran the command to "Update Custom Cookbooks" and then did a deployment, it worked.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.